# Android, Allow user to draw polyline on map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, polyline

Im trying hard to allow user to draw polyline on map when they touch on the map, i dnt know where i went wrong, I think the problem is with onMapTouch method because map displayed normally but when I touch map it says "Unfortunately application has stopped working", what you think, Here is logcat:

17319-17319/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sarahn.myapplication, PID: 17319
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
            at com.google.l.a.ce.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ft.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.sarahn.myapplication.MapsActivity.onMapClick(MapsActivity.java:91)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$8.onMapClick(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzj$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ar.a(SourceFile:93)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ac.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.bt.d(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.ak.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.h.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.h.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

```
public class MapsActivity   extends                                                                     FragmentActivit                                                                  implementsGoogleMap.OnMapClickListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    SupportMapFragment f =                                               (SupportMapFragmen)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap= f.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    PolylineOptions p = new PolylineOptions();
    p.color(Color.RED);
    p.width(5);
    arrayList.add(latLng);
    p.addAll(arrayList);
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());



    }
```

Comment: please post your logcat here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have to do with the fact that the [position](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#position(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) method of MarkerOptions returns the object to which you are setting the position.

Try:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions = markerOptions.position(latLng);
```

EDIT:

I was wrong above. It is because of this line of code:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());
```

You are adding a new marker on the map with no position. You need to set the position of the marker before attempting to add to the map. I am unsure of why you are adding a second marker to the map since you already have added the one at the user's touch location. You are also trying to add a polyline to the map with no attributes.

Try this and see what happens:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(latLng);
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
PolylineOptions p = new PolylineOptions();
p.color(Color.RED);
p.width(5);
arrayList.add(latLng);
p.addAll(arrayList);
mMap.addPolyline(p);
```

Comment: Now the Error is     IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options